# Volatile String Java

Tags: java, string, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile

I need to have a *volatile* string, that displays time. 
I declared it like this:
`public static volatile String timeTaken;`
Later I assign current time to it like this:

```
DateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
timeTaken = "Picture taken at " + time.format(start);
```

It is *never* changed and I want to use it in other threads just to display it as info.

Is it enough for it to be *thread-safe*? Thanks!

Comment: This is hard to say. Thing is - you have a code problem, but the code you are providing doesnt allow us to help by far. Please read about: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... we cant help based on such input ;-(

Comment: Are the `String` member variable and the `DateFormat` variable both named `time`? That doesn't look correct.

Comment: oh, sorry, my String variable is named Time, I edited the question!

Comment: Don't use Uppercase var name, In java there is also class called Time

Comment: oh, ok, I'll change it, thanks!

Comment: If it never changes, can you just make it final?

Comment: Would it be thread safe?

Comment: If it's final, yes. Only because the `String` class is immutable.